# Get original height of element after it has been altered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I get the height at which an element was rendered, after I have changed it's height?

E.g. the text make a very long (high) `div`, then I shorten it to make it look neat and I use `overflow:hidden` to temporarily cut off excess text. Now, dynamically, I want to resize the `div` to be as high as it would have been if I never touched it.

How is this possible to do?

CSS & JQuery is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab that value prior to the re-size.

You can then save it, and use it, in two different ways:

```
// grab it as a JS value and keep it stored somewhere
var originalHeight = element.height();

// grab and store the original value in the rel HTML attribute
el.attr("rel", el.height()
```

Comment: It's dynamic and in different functions etc, so it would become a mess :/

Comment: Then do it dynamically. Attach a variable to every DIV you're moving and keep the original value. As soon as you change it in the DOM, as fair as I can tell, it no longer is kept. One thing you can do, it to store the original value in a field of the element. Gonna update answer to reflect it.